# Eclipse Project Manager in IntelliJ?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, ide

I used to use Eclipse for programming in Java, but I'm trying to make the switch to IntelliJ. One thing I really need from Eclipse is the ability to quickly switch between projects. I'm a student so it's very helpful to be able to click between different coding assignments I've made for reference.

In Eclipse, all my projects were to the side in the Project Manager. I can't seem to do the same thing in IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ has a separate window for each project instead of a single window with all projects.  Just open those you need. Workspaces used to be a joke - hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you mean Eclipse **workspaces** rather than Eclipse projects? If so then this background on a key difference between Eclipse and IntelliJ might help:

> The first thing you'll notice when launching IntelliJ IDEA is that it has no workspace concept. This means that you can work with only one project at a time. While in Eclipse you normally have a set of projects that may depend on each other, in IntelliJ IDEA you have a single project that consists of a set of modules.

More details on moving from Eclipse to IntelliJ [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/eclipse.html).

So it *might* be the case that you don't need to switch projects in IntelliJ , since you could create an IntelliJ project which contains multiple modules. However, it is possible to switch between currently open projects in IntelliJ using keystrokes or a menu. From [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/switching-between-projects.html):

> To switch between the currently opened projects, do one of the following
>
> On the main menu, choose Window | Next Project Window/Previous Project Window.
>
> Press ⌘ `or ⇧⌘`.
>
> On the main menu, point to Window, and then select the name of the desired project.

Here's a screenshot showing the keystrokes for me (yours may differ depending on your chosen keymapping)

[image]